# SQL 4 tables query

Tags: sql, join, task

can someone help me with queries i wrote, and they didn't work correctly, maybe except the first one.

We have 4 tables with - columns:

```
table_cars - id | brand | type | license
table_equipments - id | name | description
table_distances - id_car | date | distance
table_cars_equipments - id_car | id_equipment
```

And the questions:

1. Show all cars that have equipment "fire extinguisher" and have been driving yesterday
2. Show all brands with no equipments
3. Show total distance driven by car "xxxx" in the last month
4. Show average distance per day driven by cars from "some description"

My solution:

```
   SELECT 
  table_cars.id,
  table_cars.brand,
from table_equipments
INNER JOIN table_cars_equipments  ON table_equipments.id     =  table_car_equipments.id_equipment 
INNER JOIN table_cars  ON table_cars .id     = table_cars_equipments.id_car
INNER JOIN table_distances ON table_distances.id_car = table_cars.id
WHERE table_equpments.name = 'fire extinguisher'
  AND table_date.date = NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAYS;

SELECT
table_cars.brand
from table_cars
INNER JOIN table_cars_equipments  ON  table_cars_equipments.id_car   =  table_cars .id 
WHERE table__car_equpments.id_equipment = 0 OR NULL

SELECT table_cars.license,
sum(distance) as distance,
from table_distances
inner join table_cars on table_distances. Id_car = table_cars.id
where table_distances.date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAYS
and table.distances.date <= NOW()

SELECT Avg(distance) as avg_dist
from( 
SELECT table_distances.distance,
Count(*) as dist
from table_distances
INNER JOIN table_cars_equipment ON table_dustances.id_car = table_cars_equipments.id_car
INNER JOIN table_equipments ON  table_cars_equipments.id_equipments = table_equimpents.id
WHERE table_equipments.distance = "Ilfov"
GROUPBY table_distances.date) a;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Show all cars that have equipment "fire extinguisher" and have been driving yesterday

```
SELECT C.* FROM
TABLE_CARS C
INNER JOIN TABLE_DISTANCES D ON C.ID = D.ID_CAR 
INNER JOIN TABLE_CARS_EQUIPMENTS CE ON C.ID = CE.ID_CAR
INNER JOIN TABLE_EQUIPMENTS E ON CE.ID_EQUIPMENT = E.ID
WHERE E.DESCRIPTION = 'FIRE EXTINGUISHER'
  AND TRUNC(D.DATE) = TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1);
```

2.Show all brands with no equipments

```
SELECT DISTINCT BRAND
FROM TABLE_CARS C
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT 'X' FROM TABLE_CARS_EQUIPMENTS CE
  WHERE CE.ID_CAR = C.ID
);
```

3.Show total distance driven by car "xxxx" in the last month

```
SELECT SUM(DISTANCE) 
FROM TOTAL_DISTANCES D
INNER JOIN TABLE_CARS C ON D.ID_CAR = C.ID AND C.BRAND = 'XXX'
WHERE TO_CHAR(D.DATE,'MON') = TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MON')-1 , 'MON')
```

4.Show average distance per day driven by cars from "some description"

```
SELECT TRUNC(D.DATE) AS DAY ,AVG(DISTANCE)
FROM TABLE_CARS C
INNER JOIN TABLE_DISTANCES D ON C.ID= D.ID_CAR
WHERE C.BRAND='SOME CAR'
GROUP BY TRUNC(D.DATE);
```

Date functions Here are specific to Oracle!